# Proper distance and coordinates in Schwarzschild spacetime

Tags: black-holes, distance

Consider two points in the Schwarzschild coordinates with a line-element $ds^2=-(1-\frac{2M}{r})dt^2 + \frac{1}{1-\frac{2M}{r}}dr^2+r^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta d\varphi^2)$, where $M$ is the mass of a black hole. 
For those static points on the radial axis, $dt=d\theta=d\varphi=0$, one can evaluate the proper distance, $d$, between them: 
$$
d=\int_A^B \dfrac{dr}{\sqrt{ 1-\frac{2M}{r} }},
$$
where $B>A>2M$. 
From this, I want to calculate $B$ in terms of $d$ and $A$, however, I cannot find it. Does anyone know how to obtain this? I have tried by using Mathematica, both analytically and numerically, but still can't do it.

Comment: You must not be using *Mathematica* correctly. Even the *indefinite* integral can be done analytically, and the idea that you can’t get it to do a numerical integration doesn’t make sense because the integral is well-behaved.

Comment: I read your question again more carefully. You can get an expression for $d(A,B)$. You can’t get an expression for $B(A,d)$, as far as I know, but you can do it numerically.

Comment: @G.Smith Thanks. I'm trying to obtain the numerical one by using NSolve in Mathematica, but it doesn't give a number...

Comment: Implementation details of computational tasks are [off-topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site: “While computational physics is on topic, we are not a programming site. If your question is about implementing computational code - in particular, if it's about writing, compiling, debugging or optimizing code, or about a specific language or library - then it is off topic.” You could try asking on Mathematica StackExchange.